# ¿Como puedo dar una opción para que el usuario pueda modificar su cadena de texto introducida? usando C++

Tags: c++

Mi problema esta en que quiero remplazar una cadena completa de string. Es decir que si el usuario ingresa `"7637"` o que por error ingrese `"Bcfg87"` tenga una opcion para poder editar lo que ya puso, es decir que sea capaz de poder editar él mismo lo que introdujo. No se si puedan ayudarme, lo agradecería mucho, gracias.

Este es un pedazo del código:

```
cout << "\n\t\tDigita en la pantalla el número de la sucursal";
cout << "\n\t>> ";
Cns = getch();
NDS = "";
while (Cns != 13)
{
    if (Cns != 8)
    {
        NDS.push_back(Cns);
        cout << "*";
    }
    else if (NDS.length() > 0)
    {
        cout << "\b \b";
        NDS = NDS.substr(0, NDS.length() - 1);
    }
    Cns = getch();
}
//>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
/*Crear una funcion para poder corregir el valor ingresado o seguir
si en todo caso esta correcto 

                            cout << "\n\t\t[1]-Corregir\n\t\t";
                            cout << "\n\t\t[2]-Seguir";
                            cout << "\n\t>>";
                            cin >> ;
*/
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "editar"? ¿Quieres que aparezca en pantalla el valor anterior y puedas sobrescribir carácter a carácter o te refieres a ignorar la entrada anterior y pedir de nuevo datos?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num = 0;
    int op = 0;

    do
    {
        cout << "Ingrese el dato: ";
        cin >> num;

        system("cls");

        cout << "Dato ingresado: " << num << endl << endl;
        cout << "Segur@ que desea continuar? (1 = SI / 2 = NO)? => ";
        cin >> op;

    } while (op == 2)

    cout << "Dato final: " << num << endl << endl;
    system("pause>nul");

    return 0;
}
```